# Better Import Performance on Large Data Sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a few jobs that insert large data sets from a text file. The data is loaded via .NET's SqlBulkCopy.

Currently, I load all the data into a temp table and then insert it into the production table. This was an improvement over straight importing into production. The T-SQL insert results query was a lot faster. Data is only loaded via this method, there is no other inserts or deletes.

However, I'm back to timeouts because of locks while the job is executing. The job consists of the following steps:

1. load data into temp table
2. start transaction
3. delete current and future dated rows
4. insert from temp table
5. commit

This happens once every hour. This portion takes 70 seconds. I need to get that to the smallest number possible.

The production table has about 20 million records and each import is about 70K rows. The table is not accessed at night, so I use this time to do all required maintenance (rebuild stats, index, etc.). Of the 70K, added, ~4K is kept from day-to-day - that is, the table grows by 4k a day.

**I'm thinking a 2 part solution:**

The job will turn into a copy/rename job. I insert all current data into the temp table, create stats & index, rename tables, drop old table.

Create a history table to break out older data. The "current" table would have a rolling 6 months data, about 990K records. This would make the  delete/insert table smaller and [hopefully] more performant. I would prefer not to do this; the table is well designed with the perfect indexes; queries are plenty fast. But eventually it might be required.

Edit: Using Windows 2003, SQL Server 2008

Thoughts? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one really sneaky way is to rename the current table as TableA and set up a second table with the same structure as TableB and the same data. Then set up a view with the same name and the exact fields in the TableA. Now all your existing code will use the view instead of the current table. The view starts out looking at TableA.

In your load process, load to TableB. Refresh the view defintion changing it to look at TableB. Your users are down for less than a second. Then load the same data to TableA and store which table you should start with somewhere in a database table. Next time load first to TableA and then change the view to point to TableA then reload TableB.

Comment: I have something like this planned for testing, along with the rename plan listed above. This is also a good one, with the expense of a table hanging out

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be that your queries that read from this table should READ UNCOMMITTED, since your data load is the only place that changes data. With READ UNCOMMITTED, the SELECT queries won't get locks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Comment: I've implemented snapshots; from what I've read this is preferred to read uncommited - which I considered first but I'd have to update each query and deal with the ORM implementation (for the web app side). I thought the snapshot was my fix - it made things substantially better, but not solved completely.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using partitioned tables.  The basic idea is that you can load all of your new data into a new table, then join that table to the original as a new partition.  This is orders of magnitude faster than inserting into the current existing table.

Later on, you can merge multiple partitions into a single larger partition.

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160.aspx

Comment: Partitioned tables and indexes are available only on the Enterprise, Developer, and Evaluation editions of SQL Server. :(

Comment: Ah well.  In that case then you could fudge it using something like @HLGEM's solution, but you end up copying data around a lot.  If instead of re-pointing the view at the new table, you could keep adding new tables and each time modify the view to add a UNION ALL to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick you could use is have a delta table for the updates. You'd have 2 tables with a view over them to merge them. One table, TableBig, will hold the old data, the second table, TableDelta, will hold deltas that you add to rows in tableBig.

You create a view over them that adds them up. A simple example:

For instance your old data in the TableBig (20M rows, lot's of indexes etc)

```
ID   Col1  Col2
123     5    10
124     6    20
```

And you want to update 1 row and add a new one so that afterwards the table looks like this:

```
ID   Col1  Col2
123     5    10  -- unchanged
124     8    30  -- this row is updated
125     9    60  -- this one added
```

Then in the TableDelta you insert these two rows:

```
ID   Col1  Col2
124     2    10  -- these will be added to give the right number
125     9    60  -- this row is new
```

and the view is

```
select ID, 
       sum(col1) col1, -- the old value and delta added to give the correct value
       sum(col2) col2
from   (
           select id, col1, col2 from TableBig
           union all 
           select id, col1, col2 from TableDelta
       )
group by ID
```

At night you can merge TableDelta into TableBig and index etc.

This way you can leave the big table alone completely during the day, and TableDelta will not have many rows so overall query perf is very good. Getting the data from BigTable benefits from inexing, getting rows from DeltaTable is no issue becuase it's small, summing them up is cheap compared to looking for data on disk. Pumping data into TableDelta is very cheap because you can just insert at the end.

Regards Gert-Jan

**Update for text columns:**

You could try somehting similar, with two tables, but instead of adding, you would substitute.Like this:

```
Select isnull(b.ID,   o.ID)   Id, 
       isnull(b.Col1, o.Col1) Col1  
       isnull(b.Col2, o.Col2) col2
From   TableBig b
       full join TableOverWrite o on b.ID = o.ID
```

The basic idea is the same: a big table with indexes and a small table for updates that doesn't need them.

Comment: Most of my data is text - no summing. I'd be hard pressed to determine a delta for the updated rows. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems sound to me.  Another alternative to try would be to create the final data in a temp table, all outside of a transaction and then inside the transaction truncate the target table then load it from your temp table...something along those lines might be worth trying too.

Answer (score -1):

Get better hardware. Using 3 threads, 35.000 item batches I import around 90.000 items per second using this approach.

Sorry, but at a point hardware decides insert speed. Important: SSD for the logs, mirrored ;)

Comment: You may be right...it's about 5 years old. But it only does the SQL server - one database, and the jobs it runs. And getting a corporate USA to buy a server is....

Comment: ...your problem. Likely you have a low end IO subsystem that is just overloaded. SQL Servers require planned and "measured" hardware appropriarefor the task. Cheap low end server are not.